# Search for images in Flickr with size not smaller than x by y pixels

Tags: api, flickr

I have read Flickr API documentation and didn't find dimensions criteria for search so I suppose it's not present. Though there is getSizes method that lets me get available sizes for some specific image by its ID.
Assume I want to find images that are not smaller than 1920x1200 pixels. How do I better do it?

Answer (score 0):

Thy this (found in address bar while searching at flickr)

```
    //...
    'dimension_search_mode': 'min',
    'height': 1024,
    'width': 1024
```